# I'm creating an windows phone app using a WCF service I've created, however when I update the reference its stop recognising that it exisits?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8

My service has been working fine I've updated it a number of times when I've made changes but this time for some reason when I update it I get the error 'the type or namespace name 'Service reference 1 does not exist'

[image]

However as you can see it does. And I've tried deleting the service and readding it but it doest solve the problem. Anyone got any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right-click on the referenced service under the folder ServiceRefernce.
2. Select Configure Service Reference in the menu to access Service Reference Settings.
3. Above the list of assemblies, Select "Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies:".
4. Check in the list "System.ServiceModel" and press OK.